# Sub sequential C calls to R doesn't work

Tags: c++, r

I'm writing a c++ function that takes in a R-call and evaluates it. The function returns as expected whenever I compile with a single call to it. 
But when there are sub sequential calls to my function it gets stuck when I run the object file.

How would I re-instantiate the R instance after a single function call? 
The method below gets stuck when there are two calls to my function but works fine when I do one call.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

double result1 = calculateScalar(input2);
std::cout << "Result 1 " << result1;


double result2 = calculateScalar(input2);
std::cout << "Result 2 " <<result2;
return 0;
}


double calculateScalar(const char* RCALL){
     SEXP formula, result;
     ParseStatus status;
     R_xlen_t len;
     int errorStatus;

    try {
        Rf_initEmbeddedR(0, NULL);

        Rf_protect(formula = mkString(RCALL));

        Rf_protect(formula = R_ParseVector(formula, 1, &status, R_NilValue));



       result = R_tryEval(VECTOR_ELT(formula,0), R_GlobalEnv, &errorStatus);
       PROTECT(result);

       len = xlength(result);


       UNPROTECT(3);
       Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
       return (double) getNumericScalar(result);

} catch(std::exception& e){
     std::cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what();
}

//Clean up R
Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could just RInside:

```
edd@brad:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ make rinside_sample3
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
 -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused \
 -pedantic -Wall    rinside_sample3.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp\
 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm \
 -lblas -llapack  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -lRInside \
 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -o rinside_sample3
edd@brad:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$
```

builds it (automagically using an automated `GNUmakefile) from [this simple source file](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/blob/master/inst/examples/standard/rinside_sample3.cpp).

Running it yields:

```
edd@brad:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ ./rinside_sample3 

Call:
lm(formula = Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-15.2743  -5.2617   0.5032   4.1198  15.3213 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      66.91518   10.70604   6.250 1.91e-07 ***
Agriculture      -0.17211    0.07030  -2.448  0.01873 *  
Examination      -0.25801    0.25388  -1.016  0.31546    
Education        -0.87094    0.18303  -4.758 2.43e-05 ***
Catholic          0.10412    0.03526   2.953  0.00519 ** 
Infant.Mortality  1.07705    0.38172   2.822  0.00734 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.165 on 41 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7067,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.671 
F-statistic: 19.76 on 5 and 41 DF,  p-value: 5.594e-10



And now from C++

                       Estimate      Std. Error         t value        Pr(>|t|)
     (Intercept)        66.9152          10.706         6.25023     1.90605e-07
     Agriculture      -0.172114       0.0703039        -2.44814       0.0187272
     Examination      -0.258008        0.253878        -1.01627        0.315462
       Education       -0.87094        0.183029        -4.75849      2.4306e-05
        Catholic       0.104115       0.0352579         2.95297      0.00519008
Infant.Mortality        1.07705         0.38172         2.82157      0.00733572

edd@brad:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$
```

A few things to note:

- I picked this example (among literally dozens of other in the package) as it contains multiple `eval...()` calls in the C++ code.
- It is also cute as it redoes `lm()` for you.
- The actual compilation following `make rinside_sample3` will vary from system to system; on mine it reflect some parameters I set in `~/.R/Makevars`
- I manually narrow the display by four spaces to make it fit.

Comment: Hey Dirk thanks for the reply, I would love to use RInside (had built it the other day,  examples run fine on my windows machine) but unfortunately for commercial purposes I can not. Thus I've been trying to write something much lighter that just works on string inputs. But am running into this roadblock as R is instantiated per function call and not from main.

Comment: RInside (and Rcpp and ...) are all under same license as R itself. So if you think you cannot use RInside (or Rcpp or ...) then you also **cannot use R**.

Comment: My fault did not see the licensing. I am running RInside but am getting the same error as above when I instantiate RInside each time in a different function instead of main, it compiles but the object file stalls when there are two function calls.

Comment: Do not instantiate anew. Instantiate once, keep a reference to it -- plenty of examples in the RInside sources.  R does not shut down cleanly enough to support what you want to do. You simply can't.